# Saving a field generated in ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, save, angularjs-ng-repeat

So, what I need here is to save a data in an array for every field generated in ng-repeat. My code looks something like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat = "feature in filteredFeatures">
        <td>{{feature.name}}</td>
        <td><input type="number" ng-model=""></td> 
</tr>
```

So, whatever the user writes on the input field I want it to be saved, but certainly I have no idea how.

Comment: Push the data via `ng-model` to an array in your controller

Comment: Hi, I'm a newbie in this Angular thing, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a model to ng-model in the input

```
<tr ng-repeat = "feature in filteredFeatures">
    <td>{{feature.name}}</td>
    <td><input type="number" ng-model="feature.name"></td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: It seems that when I try that all the fields change to the same number, but every iteration should have its own value.

Comment: Can you add a fiddle please ?

Comment: All right, I looked everywhere but I couldn't find what "fiddle" means in this context, I'm really sorry, English is not my first language. :(

Comment: Not problem man, english is not my primary language either, fiddle is this https://jsfiddle.net/ a page when you put your code working and we can play with

Comment: Okay, I got this link from jsfiddle.net:
https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=3HljjNm8PM

Answer (score 0):

All right it wasn't that hard after all.
As suggested I put an array via ng-model, but the trick was in using $index (I had no idea I could use it).
So the code ended looking like this:

```
<table class="table">
     <tr>
        <th>Feature</th>
        <th>Result</th>
     </tr>  
      <tr ng-repeat = "feature in filteredFeatures">
        <td>{{feature.name}}</td>
        <td><input type="number" ng-model="measures[$index]"></td> 
      </tr>

    </table>
```

So, hope I can help someone in the future, and thank to everyone who provided a little bit of their time.